# How to include vue-component from public folder (Laravel 5.5)

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.5

I have a blade file with next code

```
<div id="appCropper">
    <cropper-admin></cropper-admin>
</div>
```

and js file

```
let Child = {
    template: '<div>test</div>'
};


new Vue({
    el: '#appCropper',
    components: {
        'cropper-admin' : Child
    }
});
```

When i try use "require (js/component.vue") in console i see

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: Show us where you use `require`.

Answer (score 0):

References:

- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html
- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

In your app.js (entry file):

Global registration:

```
Vue.component('cropper-admin', require('./js/component.vue'));
```

Local registration:

```
import 'component' from './js/component.vue'

new Vue({
el: '#appCropper',
components: {
    'cropper-admin': component
 }
});
```

component.vue:

```
<template>
 <div>{{ text }}</div>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
   data() {
  return { text: 'test }
  }
}
</script>
```

Hope this helps to get you started